# Непонятное хранение значений времени в БД Postgres

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, время, timestamp, psycopg2

есть логгер, который записывает данные в файл и в БД, но при записи значений в столбец, где ожидается дата и время в текстовом формате, записывается непонятное значение типа float или double, хотя в файл нормально пишет.
Почему в базе хранятся такие значения и как добиться хранения нормальных значений в виде дыты и времени (timestamp например)
Код:

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from configparser import ConfigParser
    import psycopg2
    import logging
    import time
    from psycopg2._psycopg import InternalError
    #################################################
    configParser = ConfigParser()
    configFilePath = r'app_settings.conf'
    configParser.read(configFilePath)
    ##########################################
    # Config parser parameters
    database = configParser.get('db', 'database')
    host = configParser.get('db', 'host')
    user = configParser.get('db', 'user')
    password = configParser.get('db', 'password')
    sslmode = configParser.get('db', 'sslmode')
    # linking unified logging class and connected it to the database log writer (Db handler)
    import Logger
    logger = Logger.Logger.initLogging(
        "LogDB",
        "LogDB.log"
    )
    #Logging handler for PostgreSQL
    class psqlHandler(logging.Handler):
        initial_sql = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS log(
                            Created text,
                            Name text,
                            LogLevel int,
                            LogLevelName text,
                            Message text,
                            Module text,
                            FuncName text,
                            LineNo int,
                            Exception text,
                            Process int,
                            Thread text,
                            ThreadName text
                       )"""

        insertion_sql = """INSERT INTO log(
                                created,
                                Name,
                                LogLevel,
                                LogLevelName,
                                Message,
                                Module,
                                FuncName,
                                LineNo,
                                Exception,
                                Process,
                                Thread,
                                ThreadName)
                                VALUES(
                                %(created)s,
                                %(name)s,
                                %(levelno)s,
                                %(levelname)s,
                                %(message)s,
                                %(module)s,
                                %(funcName)s,
                                %(lineno)s,
                                %(exc_text)s,
                                %(process)s,
                                %(thread)s,
                                %(threadName)s
                        );"""

        def connect(self):
            try:
                self.__connect = psycopg2.connect(
                    database=self.__database,
                    host = self.__host,
                    user = self.__user,
                    password = self.__password,
                    sslmode="disable")

                return True
            except:
                return False

        def __init__(self, params):

            if not params:
                raise Exception ("No database where to log ☻")

            self.__database = params['database']
            self.__host = params['host']
            self.__user = params['user']
            self.__password = params['password']

            self.__connect = None

            if not self.connect():
                raise Exception ("Database connection error, no logging ☻")

            logging.Handler.__init__(self)

            self.__connect.cursor().execute(psqlHandler.initial_sql)
            self.__connect.commit()
            self.__connect.cursor().close()

        def emit(self, record):

            # Use default formatting:
            self.format(record)

            if record.exc_info:
                #record.exc_text = logging.defaultFormatter.formatException(record.exc_info)
                record.exc_text = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | %(name)s | %(levelname)s | %(message)s')

            else:
                record.exc_text = ""

            # Insert log record:
            try:
                #cur =  self.__connect.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
                cur = self.__connect.cursor()
            except:
                self.connect()
                cur = self.__connect.cursor()
            try:
                cur.execute(psqlHandler.insertion_sql, record.__dict__)
            except InternalError as ie:
                print(str(ie))

            self.__connect.commit()
            self.__connect.cursor().close()

    if __name__ == "__main__":

        myh = psqlHandler({''
                           'host':"localhost",
                           'user':"postgres",
                           'password':"secret",
                           'database':"postgres"})

        l = logging.getLogger("Snmp_Handler")
        l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        l.addHandler(myh)
        l.info("Table was created...")
```

[image: Результат кода:]

Comment: Начнём с вопроса, почему вы используете `TEXT` вместо `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: @Ainar-G , Я адаптировал пример отсюда:[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354321/is-this-postgresql-logging-handler-correct) под нужды своей задачи. Пытался подставлять TIMESTAMP, но выдало:

ProgrammingError: cur.execute(psqlHandler.insertion_sql, record.__dict__)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: ОШИБКА:  столбец "created" имеет тип timestamp withou
t time zone, а выражение - numeric
LINE 15:                             1545306912.4541857,
                                     ^
HINT:  Перепишите выражение или преобразуйте его тип.`

Comment: Ну, собственно, вот вам и ответ. У вас свойство `created` является числом. Либо переведите его в тип даты, либо пишите [`to_timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-datetime.html) в вашем запросе.

Comment: @Ainar-G,Если изменить как вы говорите запрос на инсёрт таким образом:https://pastebin.com/pTbkMkYQ,
то выдает следующую ошибку:                             
https://yadi.sk/i/vbE2QfBJG_PdZQ

Comment: Так зачем вы функцию внутрь подстановки-то засунули? `to_timestamp(%(created)s)`

Comment: А если делать так: https://yadi.sk/i/lzcw4KZE0u7krQ
То получается вот так: https://yadi.sk/i/xj6uLDPezZwkAQ
Не могу понять, где же может быть ошибка в синтаксисе.

Comment: Дмитрий, посмотрите внимательно мой предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: Разобрался как получить из таблицы значения в нужном формате при помощи запроса: 
select to_timestamp("created"::double precision) from public.log
Но как сформировать работающий инсерт для меня остается загадкой.
Пытаясь сформировать такой запрос: https://pastebin.com/85yYqW9M
Получаю следующее:
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "(")
LINE 2: to_timestamp("created"::double p...
Как составить правильный запрос, чтобы успешно вставить значения в поле created типа timestamp ?

Comment: Дмитрий, попробуйте наконец то, что я написал вам ещё два комментария назад. `to_timestamp(%(created)s)`. Внутри `values`.

Comment: @Ainar-G Выдает:   cur.execute(psqlHandler.insertion_sql, record.__dict__)
TypeError: 'dict' object does not support indexing

Comment: Решение для верного insert: pastebin.com/T8bqF04X

Comment: Да, как я вам и говорил. Пожалуйста, напишите ответ на свой же вопрос, и включите код *прямо в ответ.* На СО так [можно и нужно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Спасибо, исправил.

Answer (score 0):

Решение для верного insert:

```
insertion_sql = """INSERT INTO log(
                            created,
                            Name,
                            LogLevel,
                            LogLevelName,
                            Message,
                            Module,
                            FuncName,
                            LineNo,
                            Exception,
                            Process,
                            Thread,
                            ThreadName)
                            VALUES(
                            to_timestamp(%(created)s),
                            %(name)s,
                            %(levelno)s,
                            %(levelname)s,
                            %(message)s,
                            %(module)s,
                            %(funcName)s,
                            %(lineno)s,
                            %(exc_text)s,
                            %(process)s,
                            %(thread)s,
                            %(threadName)s

                    );"""
```